# Starting a new project: Start with Groovy or wait for Hydro?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm starting a new ROS project. As I was documenting myself and learning how everything worked, I noticed that ROS Hydro was releasing next month.

Is it worth waiting to start a new project or could I start right away on Groovy and eventually upgrade? If it's the latter, how hard would it be to upgrade from Groovy to Hydro?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66738/starting-a-new-project:-start-with-groovy-or-wait-for-hydro?/) by [GabK](https://answers.ros.org/users/5341/gabk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-07-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd start now with Groovy (or maybe even Fuerte like @davinci, depending on your needs).

According to [REP 003](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html), Groovy will be supported on Oneiric, Precise and Quantal. There was a [recent discussion on the mailing list](https://code.ros.org/lurker/attach/3@20130618.012326.9f28f78e.attach) regarding how to map ROS releases to Ubuntu LTS releases, but I'm not sure if it has propagated anywhere on the wiki.

You might also be interested at the recent [survey results](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzNmzxy4pVGMZHd2b1BSWVlHVHM/edit) regarding how often people upgrade their ROS distro (short version - most people do NOT upgrade immediately upon release.) There is also a [survey on which operating systems](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzNmzxy4pVGMNDdxNFNDblJTN1k/edit) are in use.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GabK](https://answers.ros.org/users/5341/gabk/) on 2013-07-08**:
Thanks! That was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would start with Groovy and upgrade when Hydro is released (soon).

The Groovy to Hydro upgrade should be straightforward.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1